# Installing PostGIS in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgis, installation

In earlier version we could install the PostGIS using the Stack Builder but now it is not showing the option of spatial extension. Can anyone help me install it?[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [doc](http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/) says

> Installers are available for 9.6 64/32-bit on stackbuilder [...]
>   Installers for PostgreSQL 10 64-bit are
>   available on experimental, and osgeo downloads and will be available
>   shortly on EDB appliction stack builder

--> it's not yet available in Stack Builder.

You can install Postrgres first, then [download](http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg10/) and install PostGIS

Comment: BTW just replaced 64-bit with the 2.4.1 installers..  I'll try to get up on stackbuilder this weekend or early next week.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a 64 bit installer from the official PostGIS website:

http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg10/

Comment: Yah sorry about that. there is something wrong with stackbuilder as a result of the 2 digit switch.  so though I uploaded them, it's not showing.  I have a call into them to fix the issue.  I'll bug them again after I release 2.4.1 this weekend if its still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Installing postgres from this link --> https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Now allows to install different versions of Postgis:
[image: Postgis install with 64 bit postgres 10 installation, from stack builder]